# Joomla Backend - Cannot login after switching to new host. "An error has occurred. 0 Cannot open file for writing log"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla, webmin

I switched to a new Host after using a free hoster for months I finally got a good vHost, but now I cannot login to my Joomla backend anymore resulting in a strange error.

[image]

This happens regardless of whether I use my correct or random credentials.
I use Webmin for most settings.
I don't have a .htaccess set up.

Here is my configuration.php:

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    public $offline = '0';
    public $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance.<br /> Please check back again soon.';
    public $display_offline_message = '1';
    public $sitename = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    public $editor = 'jce';
    public $list_limit = '20';
    public $access = '1';
    public $debug = '0';
    public $debug_lang = '0';
    public $dbtype = 'mysql';
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'xxxxxxxx';
    public $password = 'xxxx';
    public $db = 'xxxxxxxx';
    public $dbprefix = 'hdr5j_';
    public $live_site = '';
    public $secret = '';
    public $gzip = '1';
    public $error_reporting = 'none';
    public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
    public $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
    public $ftp_port = '21';
    public $ftp_user = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    public $ftp_pass = 'xxxxxxx';
    public $ftp_root = '/home/xxxxxxxx.de/';
    public $ftp_enable = '1';
    public $offset = 'Europe/Berlin';
    public $offset_user = 'UTC';
    public $mailer = 'sendmail';
    public $mailfrom = 'info@xxxxxx.de';
    public $fromname = 'xxx';
    public $sendmail = '/usr/local/bin/sendmail';
    public $smtpauth = '0';
    public $smtpuser = '';
    public $smtppass = '';
    public $smtphost = 'localhost';
    public $smtpsecure = 'none';
    public $smtpport = '25';
    public $caching = '1';
    public $cache_handler = 'file';
    public $cachetime = '15';
    public $MetaDesc = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
    public $MetaKeys = '';
    public $MetaAuthor = '1';
    public $sef = '1';
    public $sef_rewrite = '1';
    public $sef_suffix = '0';
    public $unicodeslugs = '0';
    public $feed_limit = '10';
    public $log_path = './logs';
    public $tmp_path = './tmp';
    public $lifetime = '15';
    public $session_handler = 'database';
    public $MetaRights = '';
    public $sitename_pagetitles = '2';
    public $force_ssl = '0';
    public $feed_email = 'author';
    public $cookie_domain = '';
    public $cookie_path = '';
    public $proxy_enable = '0';
    public $proxy_host = '';
    public $proxy_port = '';
    public $proxy_user = '';
    public $proxy_pass = '';
    public $mailonline = '1';
    public $robots = '';
    public $MetaVersion = '0';
    public $offline_image = 'images/psd-1.png';
    public $frontediting = '1';
    public $captcha = '0';
    public $asset_id = '1';
    public $memcache_persist = '1';
    public $memcache_compress = '0';
    public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $memcache_server_port = '11211';
    public $memcached_persist = '1';
    public $memcached_compress = '0';
    public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $memcached_server_port = '11211';
    public $session_memcache_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $session_memcache_server_port = '11211';
    public $session_memcached_server_host = 'localhost';
    public $session_memcached_server_port = '11211';
}
```

Here is my apache.conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2-common/README.Debian.gz about
# Debian specific hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf.d
#   |   `-- *
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
#   In order to avoid conflicts with backup files, the Include directive is
#   adapted to ignore files that:
#   - do not begin with a letter or number
#   - contain a character that is neither letter nor number nor _-:.
#   - contain .dpkg
#
#   Yet we strongly suggest that all configuration files either end with a
#   .conf or .load suffix in the file name. The next Debian release will
#   ignore files not ending with .conf (or .load for mods-enabled).
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections, and which
#   of these ports are used for name based virtual hosts.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/ and sites-enabled/ directories
#   contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules or virtual
#   host configurations, respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * Configuration files in the conf.d directory are either provided by other
#   packages or may be added by the local administrator. Local additions
#   should start with local- or end with .local.conf to avoid name clashes. All
#   files in conf.d are considered (excluding the exceptions noted above) by
#   the Apache 2 web server.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
## 

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
# It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
# client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
# browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
# where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
# unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
# incorrect  metadata.
#
DefaultType None


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!ADH:!EDH:!AESGCM
NameVirtualHost xxxxxxxxxxxxx:80
```

This is my site-specific config in /apache2/sites-available/:

```
<VirtualHost xxxxxxx:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1002" "#1002"
ServerName xxxxxx.de
ServerAlias www.xxxxxx.de
ServerAlias webmail.xxxxxx.de
ServerAlias admin.xxxxxx.de
DocumentRoot /home/xxxxxx.de/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/xxxxxx.de_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/xxxxxx.de_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/xxxxxx.de/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/xxxxxx.de/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/xxxxxx.de/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/xxxxxx.de/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/xxxxxx.de/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/xxxxxx.de/cgi-bin>
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.xxxxxx.de
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://xxxxxx.de:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.xxxxxx.de
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://xxxxxx.de:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
php_admin_value engine Off
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
Alias /dav /home/xxxxxx.de/public_html
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
<Location /dav>
DAV on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "xxxxxx.de"
AuthUserFile /home/xxxxxx.de/etc/dav.digest.passwd
Require valid-user
ForceType text/plain
Satisfy All
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
RewriteEngine off
</Location>
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "xxxxxx.de statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/xxxxxx.de/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://xxxxxx.de:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://xxxxxx.de:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
php_value memory_limit 32M
php_value suhosin.session.encrypt Off
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
I uploaded the site as root but the virtual server runs as an other user so it was just a ownership/permission thing (i initially changed the chmod of /logs/ and /tmp/ to 777 to find that it suddenly worked)